# Want to add extra field to Hikashop user registration section

Tags: joomla

I want to add extra field to the HikaShop user registration form for the first step of the checkout process. I could not find out the page inside the HikaShop Component actually where to add my code. Please suggest me soon.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is to create custom fields via the menu Display->Views (you have more possibilities in the commercial editions).
Otherwise,if you want to directly add your code to the form, you will have to edit the file "registration" of the view "user" via the menu Display->Views.